# Pegar 3 valores

Tags: c#, combobox

Tenho um ComboBox, que executar a seguinte pesquisa:

```
public DataTable Localizar(String valor)
{
    DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select sc.scat_loja as Loja,  sc.scat_cod as Codigo , sc.scat_nome as Descricao, c.cat_loja as LojaCategoria, sc.cat_cod as CodigoCategoria, c.cat_nome as NomeCategoria "+
        "from subcategoria sc inner join categoria c on sc.cat_cod = c.cat_cod where scat_nome like '%" +
        valor + "%'", conexao.StringConexao);
    da.Fill(tabela);
    return tabela;
}
```

no on load do form e assim:

```
private void frmCadastroSubCategoria_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    this.alteraBotoes(1);
    DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
    BLLCategoria bll = new BLLCategoria(cx);
    cbCatCod.DataSource = bll.Localizar("");
    cbCatCod.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
    cbCatCod.ValueMember = "Codigo";
   // cbCatCod.SelectedValue = "LojaCategoria";
    lblojaCat.Text = "";// ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue.ToString();
    cbCatCod.Text = "";
}
```

aonde esta **LojaCategoria** gostaria de trazer um o valor que foi cadastrado a categoria, exemplo código 1, descrição, loja que foi cadastrado

Edit**

Pessoal, vou tentar passar mais detalhes, a DateTable,  vai busca as categorias, empresa que ela foi cadastrada (loja), codigo (AUTO_INCREMENT) e a descrição da categoria.

No load do form eu carrego essas informações, a do localizar, nele trago o seguinte atualmente :

```
 cbCatCod.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
 cbCatCod.ValueMember = "Codigo";
```

traz beleza, ele pega a descrição da categoria e o codigo.

porém eu preciso que que além dessas informações, ele traga a empresa que foi cadastrado (loja)

```
cbCatCod.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
cbCatCod.ValueMember = "Codigo";
cbCatCod.ValueMember = "Loja";//aqui o codigo da empresa/loja que foi cadastrado na tabela categoria
```

Dessa forma ele trás somente o nome "Loja" ao invés do campo empresa/loja por exemplo 2, 3.....

assim que mudar o SelectedValueChanged eu preciso desse campo loja em um label.

Acho que agora ficou mais claro rsss

só lembrando pessoal, estou iniciando agora em c#, e aguado uma ideia de como fazer isso.

obrigado a todos.

Comment: A sua pergunta está sem um foco especifico: o seu ComboBox não carrega? não traz as informações? o seu método Localizar é danoso, usa uma estrutura pesada, é um dica sobe desempenho...

Comment: Olá, sim carrega,  porém só carrega o código do cadastro que vou vincular  exemplo, código =1, descrição = categoria. Além desses dois campos código e descrição, preciso do código empresa na qual foi cadastrado. Tentei colocar valueMember mas ele nao trás o código loja. Só lembrando  sou iniciante, por isso as perguntas rss valeu

Comment: `cbCatCod.SelectedItem` deve retornar um DataRowView (lembre de fazer o typecast) assim vc consegue todos os dados relacionados a sua seleção [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420043/how-to-get-selected-datarow-from-combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420043/how-to-get-selected-datarow-from-combobox)

Comment: valeu cara, obrigado